# For $x≠y$ and $2005(x+y) = 1$; Show that $\frac{1}{xy} = 2005\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}\right)$

Tags: arithmetic

**Problem:**

Let $x$ and $y$ two real numbers such that $x≠0$ ; $y≠0$ ; $x≠y$ and $2005(x+y) = 1$

1. Show that $$\frac{1}{xy} = 2005\left(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}\right)$$
2. Calculate $l$:

$$l = \frac{y}{y-x} - \frac{y-x}{y} - \frac{x}{y-x} - \frac{y-x}{x} + \frac{y}{x} - \frac{x}{y} +2 $$

For the first question, I tried to work it out with algebra; I solved for x through the equation given, then multiplied it by y and I got the value of $\frac{1}{xy} = 2005\left(\frac{1}{y-2005y^2}\right) $. Then I tried proving that $\frac{1}{y-2005y^2} =\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} $ but I failed at this.

Comment: For the first one, notice that you have $\frac{\color{red}{1}}{xy}=\color{red}{2005}(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y})$, so you could try to multiply by $xy$.

Comment: $(1/x + 1/y) = (x+y)/xy$ and $2005(x+y) = 1$

Comment: Multiply both sides of $2005(x+y)=1$ by $1\over xy$, then distribute to obtain $(x+y){1\over xy}={x\over xy}+{y\over xy}={1\over y}+{1\over x}$.

Comment: For the second part, regroup terms that have the same denominator and simplify. E.g., ${y\over y-x}-{x\over y-x}={y-x\over y-x}=1$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $$\frac{1}{xy} = 2005(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}) \iff \frac{1}{xy}=\frac{2005(x+y)}{xy}$$
   which follows immediately from the condition

---

2. $$l = \frac{y}{y-x} - \frac{y-x}{y} - \frac{x}{y-x} - \frac{y-x}{x} + \frac{y}{x} - \frac{x}{y} +2=$$$$= \frac{y}{y-x}-({1}-\frac{x}{y})-\frac{x}{y-x}-(-1+\frac{y}{x})+\frac{y}{x} - \frac{x}{y}+2=$$$$=\frac{y-x}{y-x}+2=3$$

Explanation:

- First divide the fraction into two fractions (like $\frac{y-x}{y}=1-\frac{x}{y}$)
- Cancel out the opposite terms

Answer (score 1):

For part 1, if $xy\not=0$, then

$$\begin{align}
1=2005(x+y)\implies{1\over xy}&=2005(x+y){1\over xy}\\
&=2005\left({x\over xy}+{y\over xy}\right)\\
&=2005\left({1\over y}+{1\over x}\right)\\
&=2005\left({1\over x}+{1\over y}\right)
\end{align}$$

For part 2, regroup the terms with denominators $y-x$, $y$, and $x$ and simplify:

$$\begin{align}
{y\over y-x}-{y-x\over y}-{x\over y-x}-{y-x\over x}+{y\over x}-{x\over y}+2
&=\left({y\over y-x}-{x\over y-x} \right)-\left({y-x\over y}+{x\over y} \right)+\left({y\over x}-{y-x\over x} \right)+2\\
&=\left(y-x\over y-x\right)-\left(y\over y\right)+\left(x\over x\right)+2\\
&=1-1+1+2\\
&=3
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question,

For $y \neq x$,
$$l = \frac{y}{y-x} - \frac{y-x}{y} - \frac{x}{y-x} - \frac{y-x}{x} + \frac{y}{x} - \frac{x}{y} +2 $$
$$\implies l = \left(\frac{y}{y-x} - \frac{x}{y-x}\right) - \frac{y-x}{y} - \frac{y-x}{x} + \frac{y}{x} - \frac{x}{y} +2 $$
$$\implies l= -(y-x)\left(\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{x}\right) + \frac{(y+x)(y-x)}{xy} + 3$$
$$\implies l = (y-x)\left(\frac{y+x}{xy} - \frac1y - \frac1x\right) + 3$$
$$\implies l =3$$

Comment: This looks unnecessarily complicated. Why not regroup all three pairs with the same denominator and simplify each? E.g., $-{y-x\over y}-{x\over y}=-{y\over y}=-1$.

Comment: You're right but this is how I thought about it when I first saw it.

Comment: Understood. Actually, having written out my "simpler" approach, it doesn't necessarily look all that much less complicated!

Comment: I'd say that I was expecting "something more" from this expression before I started simplifying it, I didn't want everything to cancel out the way it did.

Answer (score 0):

According to the problem, $x, y$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and $x \neq y$.

$\bullet$ For the first part,

(I) From the given, we have that
\begin{align*}
&2005(x + y) = 1\\
\implies & 2005 \cdot \frac{(x + y)}{xy} = \frac{1}{xy}\\
\implies & 2005 \cdot \bigg( \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} \bigg) = \frac{1}{xy}
\end{align*}
Hence, done!

$\bullet$ For the second part,

(II)  According to question,
\begin{align*}
l =& ~\frac{y}{y-x} - \frac{y - x}{y} - \frac{x}{y - x} - \frac{y - x}{x} + \frac{y}{x} - \frac{x}{y} + 2\\
= & ~ \bigg[ \frac{y}{y-x} - \frac{x}{y - x} \bigg] - \bigg[ \frac{y - x}{y} + \frac{x}{y} \bigg] + \bigg[ \frac{y}{x} - \frac{y - x}{x} \bigg] + 2\\
= & ~ 1 - 1 + 1 + 2\\
= &~ 3
\end{align*}
Hence, the value of $l$ is $3$.

Comment: Great minds think alike!

Comment: They do really!  ;)